# Branding an Angular app

Tags: angular

I am working on an app that needs to be built and deployed for different brands. Mostly the differences will be css only, and I thought I could get the right styles to load at runtime.

However, the following doesn't work:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { brand } from '../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple-form',
  template: `
             <div>
               {{message}}
             </div>
            `,
  styleUrls: [`./simple-form.component.${brand}.css`]
})
export class SimpleFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() message;
}
```

Note how I'm importing a string called *brand*, then using that to load the correct styles. However, at the point the *styleUrls* array is formed, *brand* is not accessible.

It is accessible once the component is rendered though.

Any ideas why this doesn't work, and if there is a recommended way of doing this?

Comment: I think the problem is the difficulty (of outright impossibility?) of using variables in Angular annotation values. I think a possible solution is to move the `styleUrls` out of the annotation and into a method which is bound to the page's HTML via a manual `<style>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your brand name to some root html element i.e. `<body>` or `<div id="root">`

And then you will be able to style application by overriding styles depending on brand.

Imagine, your brand is `microsoft`. You can add it to classes of body.

`<body class="brand microsoft">`

and then override any styles that you want for MicroSoft by using

`.brand.microsoft { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

use [tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/) it is more easy way. You can write the next code;

```
<div brand-one:color-red brand-two:color-green>text</
```